# Fuse ESB - Apache Camel: Getting NullPointerException while invoking a REST service hosted on an external web container

Tags: http, apache-camel, endpoint, fuseesb

I am getting a NullPointerException while invoking a REST webservice hosted on Tomcat. The route looks something like:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="rabbitmq:exchange:queue"/>
    <to uri="http://localhost:8080/rest-webservice/service/execute?message=${body}" /></route>
```

I have written a custom type convertor which converts the object I read from the rabbitMQ into a String XML. I need to send this as a parameter to the web service.

I used the `&lt;log message="message: ${body}" /&gt;` after reading from the rabbitMQ and the type convertor successfully converts the object into String.

`Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity with value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dynamic expressions like `${body}` in the **to** operation in an endpoint URI. Use **recipientList** instead if you need to compute a URI dynamically: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html